# Cannot access property of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentType

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Being new to SharePoint Online and all graviting technologies, I need some help to configure my SPO site with SP PowerShell.

Here, I want to get a list of items, stored in my document library, so I can then observe their content types. Here, I am using PnP modules.

The following code works and displays all my items with some data.

```
>     Connect-PnPOnline -Interactive -Url $UrlSite
>     $Items = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName
>     $Items
```

Here comes my problem: if I do $Items[x].ContentType, my PowerShell does not print anything. I am expecting to see something in my console though.

If I do $Items[x].Id, it works and prints me an Id. I have noticed that Id is just an Int type and that ContentType is a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentType type. I guess my problem stems from their, but I cannot be sure nor find a workaround.

Does anyone know what I am missing? I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: hi, if you get the members of one of your items what does it return ?? `$items[0] | get-member`
Does the `ContentType` appears in the list of properties ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your interest.

I know the Get-Member command. I use it all the time. It does return something on my items. This is the way I discoverd the "Content Type" property. I can also do something like items[x].ContentType | Get-Member, and that also prints me a list of methods and properties...

Comment: Can you try `$Items[x].ContentType.Description` or `$Items[x].ContentType.Name` ?

Comment: @Theo I did, it does not print anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found my way.

To summup my need: I wanted to get a list of items to apply a certain treatment on each of them. This treatment depended on their content type. That means that while I was running through my items, I needed to observe their content type.

By typing `$Items[x].FieldValues`, I was able to get all loaded properties that Powershell would allow me to use.

I found something like `"ContentTypeId"`, which is actualy not an int, but a more complexe object which you can access properties.

I finalized my program using this syntax then: `$Items[x]["ContentTypeId"].StringValue`

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Here, I want to get a list of items, stored in my document library, so I can then observe their content types.

Try using `Get-PnPContentType` instead to achieve this. Microsoft has additional documentation for it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpcontenttype?view=sharepoint-ps) if you need or I can try to help you in the comments and by updating this post.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I actually do not need to get the content types of my list. I need to get them all, then apply some treatment according to their own content type.